# How can I create a generic type function to extract a value from a JSON string using jsonPath() from Rest Assured?

Tags: java, rest-assured, jsonpath

Instead of this:

```
public static Object getJsonPathValue(String path, Response response) {
        return response.jsonPath().getObject(path, Object.class);
}
```

Something more like this:

```
public static <T> T getJsonPathValue(String path, Response response) {
            return response.jsonPath().getObject(path, T.class);
    }
```

I get an error when I try the second way.

Comment: what's the point of having such function? from syntax standpoint there is no that much benefit. You're just wrapping a line with another line.

Comment: Mostly experimental, just wanted to see how it could be done since I was getting an error. But I am also thinking that if I am going to use the function in like 50 places and the mechanism we use to extract data from JsonPath changes, i'd rather just do it in one place than in 50.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that:

```java
public static <T> T getJsonPathValue(String path, Response response, Class<T> t) {
    return response.jsonPath().getObject(path, t);
}
```